# Creating multiple objects in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing an app where employees of  a company can log time they spent on a particular task in a day. The employees are presented with a form where they can enter the log date and enter in the task details and the time spent on it. However on some days, employees might work on multiple tasks and would need to log time against each of these. I am looking for a way where the user is presented a link called "add another task" which will present a new set of form fields below where the additional task details can be filled in however the date will remain the same which the user filled in first. Each task will be stored as a separate record.

Comment: is the submit going to be one submit for all the tasks or multiple form submit?

Comment: one submit for all the tasks

Comment: what you can do is to have a javascript template of the form fields ( html as string in javascript). when ever user clicks on the add new task, you just add new fields via javascript with incremental names or use rails convention of array of values for a field ex"name[]"